# Update payment element styling for dark mode in Stripe.js

Tags: stripe-payments

I created a Stripe payment element per below:

```
let options = {
    appearance: {
        rules: {
            '.Label': {
                color: 'black',
            },
        },
    },
};

let stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
let elements = stripe.elements(options);
let paymentelement = elements.create('payment');
paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
```

Here I am using `rules` to style the '.Label' element to 'black', per documentation here:
https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api#rules

But what if I want the color to change to 'white' when the user switch to dark mode, how would I do that?

With CSS its just as simple as:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    color:  'white'
}
```

I tried [method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562489/how-to-change-stripe-styles-in-dark-mode), which uses the `update` api, but it does not accept `appearance` as object property and I get the error message `Unrecognized payment.update() parameter: appearance is not a recognized parameter`.

Is this still possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong `update` method - the one you're pointing to is an old one for the `card` element.

You're using the `payment` element, which runs from an `elements` instance. There is an `update` method for this instance, which supports an `appearance` object:
https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/update